# Laravel mail to variable with user model params passed

Tags: php, laravel

I need to get laravel mail as variable and to pass in it model object

```
$markdown = new Markdown(view(), config('mail.markdown'));
$html = $markdown->render($template, $user->toArray());
```

Here is the problem I am not getting relations within array and I know that I can use with to pass relations, but I am wondering is there a better way of getting laravel mail as HTML variable?
Is there maybe I way to create new mail like PHP artisan make:mail Test and then to call that test mail class and get full filled mail as HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like doing this helps:

```
return (new Welcome(User::find(1)))->build();
```

This is returning mail html